# Direct Neo4j queries from an API

Tags: neo4j

currently i'm running direct queries from an API to Neo4j.  Problems are arising such as slow queries due to so many nodes and degree of connection.

Does anyone have any recommendations on how to improve this?  Should Noe4J have a direct connection to an API?

Comment: Which neo4j version are you using?

Comment: @JFMeier v2.3.7

Comment: Are you using Neo4j in embedded mode or as a server?

Comment: Do you have slow queries or too many of them? If you have slow queries, concentrate on that and edit the question to add examples of both the data and the queries, the "API" (more likely a middleware application) is irrelevant to the problem.

Comment: please provide more context otherwise you won't get any helpful answers.